# .htaccess thumb php image link

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to make better links to thumb image with php

my current image link to thumb

> mydomain.tld/thumbimg/thumb.php?size=50x50&src=../data/filename.jpg

but I want in this form

> mydomain.tld/thumbimg/50x50/filename.jpg

I tried with this htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$ thumb.php?size=$1&src=../data/$2
# Handle requests for "thumb.php"
```

Where the error and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**
I found the solution, this is code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ -
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)\.jpg$ thumb.php?size=$1&src=../data/$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)\.png$ thumb.php?size=$1&src=../data/$2.png [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below rule in your respective directory,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.jpg$ thumb.php?size=$1&src=../data/$2 [L]
```

Comment: File cannot be found

Comment: where are you using the `.htaccess` and where is the thumb.php file?

Comment: Yes, my images is in `data` folder, thumb.php and `.htaccess` is in same folder named `thumbimg`

Comment: `File cannot be found` is error which shows the thumb.php
I used this script https://github.com/jamiebicknell/Thumb/blob/master/thumb.php

Comment: Strange working for me here you sure you don't have other rules conflicting.

Comment: I have no other rules

Comment: if you are using without rewrite it is working fine or not? try to echo both variables inside file to check they are getting value if okay then it is error from file.

Comment: Yes, if I use 
`mydomain.tld/thumbimg/thumb.php?size=50x50&src=../data/filename.jpg`
everything works fine
but when I try to `mydomain.tld/thumbimg/50x50/filename.jpg` thumb.php shows error `File cannot be found`

Comment: I make [R=301,L] redirection and found problem
Apache get data from:
`http://dimain.tld/home/CPANEL_USERNAME/public_html/folder/myproject/thumbimg/thumb.php?size=50x50&src=../data/filename` (without .jpg) How i can fix it?